# Does Flinter drop the Storm Front?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2 does Flinter, the boss you get by getting all the lights in the Splinter Groups lair green, does he drop the Storm Front with an increased chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the wiki here: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Front

Not Flinter has the increased chance to drop the Stormfront, but rather the four rats you have to fight before him.

And according to this: http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Legendary_Drop_Locations

Flinter has an increased chance to drop the Legendary Grenade Mod Rolling Thunder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the case. I had farmed him about 27 times and not once has he dropped the storm front, but it only took 5 times to get the storm front for me  by killing the 4 rats.